Spring Boot Native-Image build failed
I get following error if i try to build a native image with Spring Boot.
.\gradlew bootBuildImage

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':composite-product:bootBuildImage'.
> Illegal char <:> at index 5: npipe:////./pipe/dockerDesktopLinuxEngine

build.gradle
tasks.named('bootBuildImage') {
    imageName = "native-product-service"
    docker {
        host = "//./pipe/dockerDesktopLinuxEngine"
    }
}

Is there anything wrong. Docker-Desktop is running and working.
